# How can I modify a file in more than one project at the same time automatically?

Tags: javascript, php, android, version-control

I have a main project and some sub-projects that are similar to the main project.
The only one difference is the config file (that has some particular variables depending of the client which corresponds).

I have detected one bug in the main project so I would like to fix it in all sub-projects without copy and paste the file that I have changed manually because I have around 20-30 sub-projects.

I do not care about the language in which I would program because I have the same problem at Android projects or web development projects.

How can I modify a file in more than one project at the same time automatically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have to "update common code in all sub-projects", you should look at building a library that you reference in all your sub-projects. For example, you might build your own database library, which all of your other projects reference. When you find a bug, you just update your library.

Comment: @RobbieToyota At the moment what I am searching for is copy-paste the main project when I want to create a new project for a new client and just modify config file. If one bug is detected and changed on the main project that I could refresh that file in all the sub-projects.

Comment: At the very least, you should use a source control system like [git](https://git-scm.com/) to manage changes. This makes it trivial to bring existing systems up to date. Beyond that, you'll likely also want to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) or a similar tool to manage deployment of varying versions.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes, I am using git to have a source control system to manage changes but I think it is tedious to modify the files modified in 20-30 projects fo fix a bug...

Comment: When you say are you modifying files in 20 - 30 projects, do you mean you're manually editing them?

Comment: @AlexHowansky By the moment, yes, I am manually overwritting the files in which I have made some changes. I modify them on the main project and when I test them and I have checked that all is correct, I will fix the bug in the rest of projects. The main project is the project that I have connected with git. It is why I am searching for a way to make those changes faster and more efficiently.

Comment: All the projects should be connected to git. Then you just `git pull` to get the latest code.

Comment: @AlexHowansky But how can I connect all sub-projects to the main project?

Comment: You install them via `git clone` instead of copy/paste. Just make sure the config file is listed in your `.gitignore` so that it doesn't get committed.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank you! I will make clone copy instead of copy/paste in all projects to take in consideration from today those advices. Just one more point, is there a way to make as child projects of the main, I mean, that if you want to make a change in all children that depends of the main project, you can do it without having to make a `git pull` in each project individually.

Comment: You could write a bash script to do it, then drop that in a cron or fire it from a post-receive hook -- but automatically updating live sites is generally frowned upon. You'll likely want to use something like [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and/or [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to manage versioning.